# MYSQL between doesn't include max date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, between

To start with, I'm sorry for the format. It's my first time and I really don't know how to show tables here.

This is my syntax:

```
SELECT order.id, order.begin, order.end, report.id, 
   DATE_FORMAT( report.add_date, '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS report_add_date, sums.id, sums.qty 
FROM order, report, sums 
WHERE (report.add_date BETWEEN order.begin AND order.end) 
  AND (report.id = sums.id) 
ORDER BY order.id ASC
```

It gives the following result:

```
order.id | order.begin | order.end  | report.id | report.add_date | sums.id | sums.qty
     255 | 2013-10-21  | 2013-10-22 | 390       | 2013-10-21      | 390     | 250
     256 | 2013-10-22  | 2013-10-23 | 393       | 2013-10-22      | 393     | 385
```

The final result should look like this:

```
order.id | order.begin | order.end  | report.id | report.add_date | sums.id | sums.qty
     255 | 2013-10-21  | 2013-10-22 | 390       | 2013-10-21      | 390     | 250
     255 | 2013-10-21  | 2013-10-22 | 393       | 2013-10-22      | 393     | 385
     256 | 2013-10-22  | 2013-10-23 | 393       | 2013-10-22      | 393     | 385
```

Hopefully, you can see, that I am trying to get all sums.qty for all order.id where report.add_date is between order.begin and order.end date.

There are 3 tables: order, report and sums.
Order contains the range dates (begin-end). Report contains date (add_date). Sums contains qty and it's related to Report by id.

> Order.id 255 should get all sums.qty for dates between 2013-10-21 and 2013-10-22.
>
> Order.id 256 should get all sums.qty for dates between 2013-10-22 and 2013-10-23.
>
> The first one doesn't get sums.qty for the date of 2013-10-22, because this one goes to the latter.

As far as I understand, it doesn't repeat rows, so it shows every row only ones. So it stops assigning report.id to the previous order.id when the following order.id begins with the date the previous one ends.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `add_date`  is a `DATETIME` and you're not converting it to `DATE` in your `BETWEEN` criteria.  A date has a 0 time, so though `BETWEEN` is inclusive it won't include the same date if there is a non-zero time portion attached to it.

I'd also suggest switching to explicit joins as implicit joins have been deprecated for ages.

Comment: Of course it does work :) Thanks!
I don't know much about explicit joins (need to re-educate myself). Would you be so kind to transform this joins to explicit ones this single time? Cheers